# How to push message from Activemq

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

i am new to activemq. i read some article and doing this.please help me to solve the following task.
i produce one message to activemq from my java application and i have a consumer for that message in another java application.so i will get the message from activemq. every time this consumer(listener) looking for the message in activemq. my question is activemq can push the message to consumer(listener).

activemq only for storing the message ? it will do any push or pull operation ? activemq always need producer(produce the message) and consumer(consume the message) ?

can anyone help me

thanks

Comment: Need code, better explanation of the problem and the use case etc.

Comment: @TimBish my question is activemq able to push the message to any consumer ? . there should be one consumer for consume the message .if i am wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ActiveMq, WebLogic, IBM MQ, and any JMS compatible provider are destination-based messaging systems; the destination, or subject, is a **queue** or **topic**. When sending a message, producer can send the message and disconnect immediately; ActiveMq will store message on queue. When receiving, message consumer can receive sync or async, independent of sender.

[image]

### Send Message

Message producer sends message to destination; it's job is done.

```
QueueSender queueSender = queueSession.createSender(myQueue);
queueSender.send(message);
```

### Receive Message

Message consumer can receive message one of two ways:
**Synchrounous**, here you call `receive()` explicitly

```
QueueReceiver queueReceiver = queueSession.createReceiver(myQueue);
queueConnection.start();
Message m = queueReceiver.receive();
```

**Asynchronous**, here you implement callback method from `MessageListener` interface:

```
class MyQueueReceiver implements javax.jms.MessageListener {

    QueueReceiver queueReceiver = queueSession.createReceiver(myQueue);
    queueReceiver.setMessageListener(this);
    ...
    public void onMessage(Message msg){
      //consume message here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply . so my question is activemq can't push message to any consumer right. there should be one consumer for consume the message from activemq.if i am wrong please correct me.

Comment: For queues, it doesn't matter how many consumers exist, only one consumer will get the message. For topics, all subscribers get the same messages. ActiveMq does not select the consumer because JMS is basically a _pull_ system from receiver perspective; the broker does not push.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: Is there a service to push data?
Reason: In the SaaS age, a message queue system is generally part of an integration platform that can actively manage distribution. Most cloud systems have passive open APIs, not active APIs.